# Where in Apache 2 do you set the ServerName directive globally?

Tags: debian, configuration, apache-httpd

**NOTE:** This is related to my question: "[Apache 2.4 won't reload, any problem with my configuration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154811/apache-2-4-wont-reload-any-problem-with-my-configuration/)".

I'm trying to test a local site, locally. As I understand Apache 2 (and perhaps Apache as well) has something called `VirtualHost`. My little bit of understanding tells me that virtualhosting is a way where one server/IP address can serve multiple domains.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting .

Anyway, I'm getting the following error when running Apache 2's `configtest` to see where I'm failing. I'm running Apache 2.4.10-1, and it seems there are a lot of changes which have happened between Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 which I'm not aware of.

```
$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
[sudo] password for shirish:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

This is the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
 $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    debian mini
```

I also see an empty `/etc/hosts.conf` file. Perhaps the data in `/etc/hosts` needs to be copied to `/etc/hosts.conf` for the server to take cognizance?

My hostname:

```
$ hostname
debian
```

This is the configuration file of the site:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/minidebconfindia.conf
<VirtualHost mini:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/in2014.mini/website

    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/in2014.mini/website/>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also [read about binding to addresses and ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html), but I haven't understood that well for multiple reasons. It doesn't give/share an example as to in which file those lines need to be put and what will come before and after. An example would have been much better.

I did that and restarted the server, but I still get the same error.

```
~$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

It seems there are three configuration files in Debian that I need to know and understand.

```
/etc/apache2$ ls *.conf
apache2.conf  ports.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d$ ls *.conf
httpd.conf
```

Apparently, apache2.conf IS the global configuration file while the httpd.conf is a user-configuration file. There is also ports.conf. Both apache2.conf and ports.conf are at the defaults except I have changed the loglevel of Apache from `warn` to `debug`.

I tried one another thing:

```
$ sudo apache2ctl -S
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.1.1:80           debian (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/minidebconfindia.conf:1)
*:80                   127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Maybe somebody has more insight.

Answer (score 80):

The file to edit:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Command to edit file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

For a global servername you can put it at the top of the file (outside of virtual host tags).

The first line looks like:

**`ServerName myserver.mydomain.com`**

Then save and test the configuration with the following command:

```
apachectl configtest
```

You should get:

> Syntax OK

Then you can restart the server and check you don't get the error message:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This is the Debian correct answer. I tried `/etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf`, or `servername.conf` or `httpd.conf` to no avail. Debian `Jessie`, and `apache 2.4.10`

Comment: If you have `conf-available/` and `conf-enabled/`, create a file in `conf-available/` and use the command `a2enconf` to enable it. This way, dpkg will not annoy you about untracked changes when/if the `apache2-common` package updates `apache2.conf`

Comment: The file in `conf-available` after this and an edit might be `/etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf` with content `ServerName myserver.mydomain.com` (tried on Raspberry Pi, Apache 2.4.10, Debian 8 (Jessie), Linux kernel 4.4.34).

Comment: @PeterMortensen could you use the example shared so I can understand what you mean.

Comment: The file does not exist

Answer (score 14):

You must set [ServerName directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername):

```
ServerName localhost
```

In Debian, you can set it in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/httpd.conf`.

On macOS, you can set it in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Comment: In Ubuntu, set it in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Debian either: `apache2.conf`.

Comment: What versions of Apache/Debian does this work for? I don't think it works for Apache 2.4. It could be `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` instead.

Comment: it works, Apache 2.4 on Debian 8

Comment: Everything gets more complicated. Setting it near the top of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf works, there's a "Global configuration" label but it's just a comment.  On a LAN with NAT your servername can be the machine's hosthname that's in /etc/hostname.  If you use static IPs you can put your IP in there.  Using Apache 2.4.25.  apache2ctl is in /usr/sbin which is maybe not in all user's paths.

Comment: I like this solution of using *localhost* best because I found that Apache assigns this "global" *ServerName* to the first *VirtualHost* it finds that does not contain a *ServerName*, which can be very confusing.

Answer (score 6):

To locate your Apache configuration file, try running the following command:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

Then edit that file and locate line with `ServerName` and uncomment it, so it looks like:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a few years late to the party ... 2023. I'm on Raspian, Apache2, I ran this command to find `ServerName` ...

```
find /etc/apache2 -type f -exec grep -s ServerName {} \;
```

I found it in `sites-available/000-default.conf`, in the `VirtualHost` configuration, nowhere else. I would think the correct file for `ServerName` would have it in place already, perhaps commented out, as it is where I found it.

Comment: `grep -R ServerName /etc/apache2/*` also works, no need to use `exec`.

Comment: @dr_ Does using exec cause problems?

Comment: It's unnecessary here.  Always do things the simplest possible way (but not simpler, as Einstein used to say).

Comment: @dr_ Are you sure? I thought that was Ghandhi ... ;)

Comment: I understand the philosophy of simpler is better, but this is not a production script, it would be run probably one time, why worry about it? If this was to be run frequently, then optimization is warranted.

Comment: I'm gong to side with user3481644 here. The correct answer states that ServerName should be in the top-level file. It works just fine if you put the line there, but it isn't originally there, even commented out. This makes the original answer outdated.

Answer (score 0):

In apache24 config file, you will see the line `ServerName:80`:

1. Leave it blank.
2. Then below that line in the empty space write:
   `ServerName www.name (of your official domain or website.com:80)`
3. Save the config file.
4. Go to `cmd`, open it as administrator change `dir` to where apache24 is
5. Then `cd apache24` then `cd bin` then httpd.exe

You will see the problem is solved.